# Why isn't thunder muted or softened by rain drops?

Tags: energy, acoustics, absorption, lightning, weather

I watched a documentary showing how NASA applied water droplets to absorb the huge amount of sound energy when the rocket is ignited at launch. So, how come billions of rain drops don't seem to mute or soften the sound of thunderclaps?

Comment: Who says that they don't?

Comment: The fact that A is loud in the presence of B does not mean that B doesn't make it dimmer, unless you have access to an equally-powerful A in the absence of B, and it turns out to be equally loud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical wavelengths in thunderclaps are vastly greater than the diameters of raindrops.  Consequently, the pressure around each drop is almost isotropic, and the drop is barely distorted.  Water is almost incompressible, so bulk viscosity won’t come into play.  (The physics would be very different if the wavelength were < 2 mm.  Shear viscosity would matter.)